# Sequential convergence to derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose for the function $f$ the derivative $f'(c)$ exists and we have sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = c$, and $x_n \neq y_n$.

> Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n}
>  = f'(c)?$

My approach:

$$\frac{f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n} = \frac{x_n - c}{x_n - y_n}\frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c} -  \frac{y_n - c}{x_n - y_n}\frac{f(y_n) - f(c)}{y_n - c} $$

(Case 1) Now if $x_n < c < y_n$ we can write

$$\frac{f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n} = \lambda_n\frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c} +  (1 - \lambda_n)\frac{f(y_n) - f(c)}{y_n - c} $$

where $\lambda_n = \frac{c - x_n}{y_n - x_n}$ and $0 < \lambda_n < 1$.

Let $M_n  = max(\frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c},\frac{f(y_n) - f(c)}{y_n - c})$ and $m_n  = min(\frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c},\frac{f(y_n) - f(c)}{y_n - c})$

Then

$$m_n <  \frac{f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n} < M_n$$

Since $m_n, M_n \to f'(c)$ ( is this correct?) it must hold by squeeze theorem that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n) - f(y_n)}{x_n - y_n}
 = f'(c).$

(Case 2) If the order $x_n < c < y_n$ does not hold then is the theorem true? I think not but can't find a counterexample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f(x) = x, x\le 0.$ For $x>0,$ we can define $f$ to be piecewise constant function that is between $x$ and $x+x^2.$   Then $f'(0) = 1,$ but because there exists sequences $0<x_n<y_n \to 0^+$ along which $f(y_n)=f(x_n),$ we have a counterexample for case (2).